# Hide any contents or elements loading from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, iframe

**For example: tried to hide the wiki-logo by hiding the class ("#central-featured-logo" which is associated with the wiki logo) but didn't work**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
 try {
       if(window.name != "") 
       {
         document.getElementById("#central-featured-logo").style.display ='none';
       }   
     }  
    catch (e) { alert("Error:  " + e); }
});
</script>
```

```html
<iframe  width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Tried this Class instead of the other? .central-textlogo {
    display: none;
}

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: it aint stopping the logo from loading  & showing up

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass along the hashtag to `document.getElementById`. It also appears that `central-featured-logo` is a class, not an ID, so you would want to use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 try {
       if(window.name != "") 
       {
         document.getElementsByClassName("central-featured-logo")[0].style.display ='none';
       }   
     }  
    catch (e) { alert("Error:  " + e); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.The main objective is to stop the logo from loading/showing up & it's still not serving the purpose.

Comment: I think the issue you are running into is probably the [same origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) policy.

Comment: .yes you are right.. what if i load the page using ajax,jscript etc instead of iframe? i mean how to avoid "same origin policy" ?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important) on why the same origin policy is important, and why it's in place. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) on ways to circumvent this restriction.

Comment: ........tried to load the page without iframe & applied your corrections. Can you please see what's wrong over here: 
[link]http://codepad.viper-7.com/zlAplp